# Media is not defined in phonegap android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I am developing one app in phonegap older version and now I have added RevMob ads to my app after that Media is not defined error is throwing in Logcat.
I have tried to add media plugin using this command in cli cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media then current working project directory is not cordova based project error getting in command prompt. 
Other than Media plugin for sound is there anything to play sound in phonegap?
Media Code : 
     var my_media = null;
     var mediaTimer = null;

```
    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio22(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess22, onError22);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
       /* if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }*/
    }

    // Pause audio
    //
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    //
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess22() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback
    //
    function onError22(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    //
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }
```

When clicked
      $('#playId_1').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
        playAudio22('/android_asset/www/MenuBtnclicksound.mp3');
        revmob.showFullscreen(onSuccess, onError);
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

```
});
```

Logcat error
11-19 12:42:11.805: E/Web Console(9770): Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/sounds.js:8

```
  Config.xml
  <feature name="Media" >
    <param
        name="android-package"
        value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />
  </feature>
```

ANd also I tried to create cordova project with higher version 3.6+ in eclipse its not taking any modification also, whenever I change index.html file under www directory its not affecting in device.
I am running project in eclipse.
[image: New project directory]

[image: Media is not defined error project directory]

Comment: What's the "older version" of phonegap you're using? The CLI is for cordova/phonegap>=3.x and to use the cli you have to cd to the folder in wich the www folder is (the project's root folder). Have you included phonegap.js in your index.html file?

Comment: About changing the root www folder, you need to run `cordova prepare android` to make the change come to the platforms/android/assets/www folder. Or you can change directly files in platforms/android, but then you MUST no more use the CLI or your changes would be overwritten : in that case you build using eclipse and add plugins using plugman.

Comment: Phongap 2.9.0 version im using.. in that version project structure is different so im confused

Comment: In phonegap 2.9 core plugins like Media were included by default, you shold have nothing to do. Did you include phonegap-2.9.js in your index.html (sorry don't remember the exact name of the file, it's been a long time since I used 2.x)

Comment: Ya I have included cordova.js.. If i include cordova-3.0.0.js file then it will throw error

Comment: have the same problem with cordova 5.1